# Using article twice when joining two clauses

Tags: gramática, pronombres, artículos

I am trying to translate `That's the one that I eat the chicken with'` 
What I currently have is `Esa es la con la que como el pollo`, which doesn't sound right to me.

So I start with the first half of the sentence: `That's the sauce that I eat`. I translate this as `Esa es la salsa que como` /

Then suppose that we already know that I'm talking about a sauce. I would say in English `That's the one (that) I eat`, which I translate to Spanish as `Esa es la que como`.

Now for the stranded preposition. Take the sentence `That's the sauce that I eat the chicken with`. My translation for this is `Esa es la salsa con la que como el pollo`.

Then comes the problem. When I want to do both of these processes; ie. refer to the sauce from a previous sentence without saying the noun 'salsa' explicitly, and move in the stranded preposition, I get my sentence from above

> Esa es la con la que como el pollo

But the `la con la que` doesn't feel right to me. Can anyone help me translate this properly?

Also, if anyone could tell me what role that chunk is playing in the sentence that would be great too? It's like when we use 'quien' as a relative pronoun, but there's no pronoun so I was a bit stuck for what to call it. Maybe it's a 'relative prepositional phrase' or something...

Thanks very much!

Comment: el problema está con el "one". Tienes que decir que ese "one" no puedes escaparle, queda incoherente en español. Incluso en inglés lo necesitas, si lo remueves pierde sentido la oración. Lo más cercano en español a la funcionalidad que estás buscando es usar "aquél/aquella". Ejemplo. Aquella es la que uso con el pollo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Spanish we have several constructions that can translate your sentence, *That's the one that I eat the chicken with*:

- *Es con esa que me como el pollo*
- *Con esa es con la que me como el pollo*
- *Es con esa con la que me como el pollo*
- *Esa es con la que me como el pollo*

Maybe the most grammatically correct is the first one, but I'd say the other three constructions are more usual.